# Can i consider it as a insertion sort

Tags: javascript, algorithm, sorting, data-structures, insertion-sort

i am learning DSA and tried this in my own please tell me is this algorithm is insertion sort or not. and guide me...thank you

```
function insertion(number){
    let length = number.length;
    for(let i = 0; i< length; i++){
        let num = i;
        while(number[num] < number[num-1]){
            let temp = number[num-1];
            number[num-1] = number[num];
            number[num] =temp;
            num--;
        }
    }
    return number;
}
console.log(insertion([3,2,4,6,5,1,2,-1]))
```

Output = [ -1, 1, 2, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6 ]

Comment: This is bubble sort.

Comment: Yes, this is a non-optimised insertion sort. *"guide me"* is not a suitable question on this site. If you encounter a problem in your attempt, then focus your question on that.

Answer (score 0):

You can compare your code with the pseudo code provided by [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Insertion_sort#Algorithm), specifically the first version they provide:

```
i ← 1
while i < length(A)
    j ← i
    while j > 0 and A[j-1] > A[j]
        swap A[j] and A[j-1]
        j ← j - 1
    end while
    i ← i + 1
end while
```

The notable difference is that in your code:

- the outer loop variable starts at 0 instead of 1, and
- the inner loop does not test whether the inner loop variable is still greater than 0

That means that the `while` condition in your code will sometimes evaluate `number[0] < number[-1]`. -1 is not an existing index and in other languages that could produce an exception. JavaScript returns `undefined` for `number[-1]` which luckily makes the `while` condition false, and so it works correctly in JavaScript.

Secondly, you'll want to read the referenced Wikipedia article to see how this version can be made "slightly faster".